# Storing user input in empty arraylist

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am working on an exercise where the user can create a new book entry or look for an existing book by searching with a keyword.

1. If the user clicks on the 'Create Book' button, the fields under 'Create a new book' become enabled. The user populates the textBoxes. Then when the user clicks 'Execute' button, a Book object should be created and takes on those values from the textBoxes. Then that Book object should be placed in a BookList array.
2. If the user clicks on the 'Search for Book' button, the field under 'Search for a book' become enabled. Basically the user would type in a keyword and press execute, and all the books containing that keyword get displayed in a message.

I feel that part (2) isnt that bad. It is just going through the BookList and comparing the users input to the keywords that are in that book object. The difficult part for me is trying to go about part (1). My assumption is there has to be two other classes, Book.class (creates the book objects from the given user input) and BookList.class (creates booklist array to have the book objects stored in).

[image: Visual Studio Form]

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour], then decide if it is VB or c# and dont use ArrayList after 2005

Comment: oh wow, sorry about that, I meant Visual Studio, not visual basic. I am using C# and Visual Studio. I didnt even realize what I wrote.

Answer (score -2):

To solve (1) - yes you need the `Book` class - which represents a single instance of `Book`. However, you can use a Collection (System.Collections or System.Collections.Generic) to hold multiple `Book` objects for you.

Read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

to quote an example:
This creates a collection which can hold strings.

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
```

Now I can collect as many strings as I want using:

```
strList.Add("Hello");
strList.Add("Berman");
strList.Add("Friend");
```